# Pandas find content by label not working

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas

Getting Key error in Python (3.5) pandas (0.22.0) under the following circumstances.
importing this csv data for example:

```
'First', 'Name', 'Second', 'Number', 'Another Number', 'Random Exclamation', 'Time', 'Left', 'Anyway'
91004, 'Freddy', 1.518990585, 1.1000082, 5790, 'Hooray', 7241606319.947, 1939238254.77354879, 1.215094577191377
```

I import it thus:

```
test=pd.read_csv('test.csv')
```

I can do this:

```
>>> test.dtypes
'First'                   int64
'Name'                   object
'Second'                float64
'Number'                float64
'Another Number'          int64
'Random Exclamation'     object
'Time'                  float64
'Left'                  float64
'Anyway'                float64
dtype: object
```

and this:

```
>>> test.loc[0]
'First'                       91004
'Name'                     'Freddy'
'Second'                    1.51899
'Number'                    1.10001
'Another Number'               5790
'Random Exclamation'       'Hooray'
'Time'                  7.24161e+09
'Left'                  1.93924e+09
'Anyway'                    1.21509
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

And this:

```
>>>test.loc[0][0]
91004
```

But if I try this:

```
>>>test.loc['First']
```

or this:

```
>>>test.loc[0, 'First']
```

I get this:

```
KeyError: 'the label [First] is not in the [index]'
```

This is the most concise example of my problem. I have tried many combinations of trying to access data by label which I won't bore you with and none of them work. I have tried lots of similar test data as well as removing all the spaces from the csv on the off chance but it makes no difference.
How on earth do I access data in my frame by label?
I am new to pandas and have googled this for hours. This usually means I am being very stupid so any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing inner quotation marks. In Python, quotation marks (single or double) may denote a string, so you need to use double outer quotes with single inner quotes. Try this instead:

```
test.loc[0, "'First'"]
```

I strongly advise you clean up the column names by removing punctuation and leading / trailing whitespace:

```
test.columns = test.columns.str.replace('[^\w\s]','').str.strip()
```

Comment: Thanks you. Cleaning up the column names as you suggest also means I can apply things like test.first and basically solves this issue.